# How can i execute a function and have it return an array of all emails using the imap module?

Tags: node.js, email, imap

I have searched and searched and this callback hell is stressful.

I would've liked to be able to do what i did with mongodb and just delete the callback and put await in front but that doesn't work here.

i want a function called "getEmails" and i simply want it to return a list of all emails in the inbox.

Comment: any code snippet ?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: I need to take a look at the code. please contact here: https://www.facebook.com/talha.aiubian